# Compilation error bouncycastle java

Tags: java, bouncycastle

This is my first time working on certifications and I am totally new to this.
I had an error during compilation and I found nothing on the internet about it, nothing with the same error was found. I'm struggling on it since 4 days I couldn't do anything :( I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

here is my code:
main class

```
package tn.ance.signature;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
public class main_project {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        chargement_fichier cf = new chargement_fichier();
        KeyStore ks = cf.charger_fichier();
        char[] password = cf.getPassword();
        // RECUPERATION DU COUPLE CLE PRIVEE/PUBLIQUE ET DU CERTIFICAT PUBLIQUE
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        PrivateKey privatekey = null;
        PublicKey publickey = null;

        recuperation_cles_cert recup =new recuperation_cles_cert(); 
        privatekey = recup.getPrivatekey();
        publickey = recup.getPublickey();
        cert = recup.getCert();

        System.out.println("Private Key Format:");
        System.out.println(privatekey.getFormat());
        System.out.println("Private Key Algorithme:");
        System.out.println(privatekey.getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println("Public Key Format:");
        System.out.println(publickey.getFormat());
        System.out.println("Public Key Algorithme:");
        System.out.println(publickey.getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println("Certification:");
        System.out.println("SubjectDN:");
        System.out.println(cert.getSubjectDN());
        System.out.println("Not After:");
        System.out.println(cert.getNotAfter());
        System.out.println("Not Before:");
        System.out.println(cert.getNotBefore());

    }
}
```

**

file uploading class

```
package tn.ance.signature;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Security;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
public class chargement_fichier {
     private char[] password = null;
    // CHARGEMENT DU FICHIER PKCS#12
     public KeyStore charger_fichier(){
            KeyStore ks = null;
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            try {
                ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
                // Password pour le fichier personnal_nyal.p12
                password = "123456".toCharArray();
                FileInputStream fl = new FileInputStream("T:/Stage/150722/syrine.p12");
                ks.load(fl, password);
                return  ks;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erreur: fichier " +
                                   "syrine.p12" +
                                   " n'est pas un fichier pkcs#12 valide ou passphrase incorrect");
                return null ;
            }
         }
      public char[] getPassword(){
             return password;
             }
}
```

key and certifications loading

```
package tn.ance.signature;
    import java.security.KeyStore;
    import java.security.PrivateKey;
    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
    import java.util.Enumeration;
    import java.util.Vector;
    public class recuperation_cles_cert {
        private X509Certificate cert = null;
        private PrivateKey privatekey = null;
        private PublicKey publickey = null;
        private KeyStore ks;
        private char[] password;

    public PrivateKey getPrivatekey(){

        chargement_fichier cf = new chargement_fichier(); 
        ks = cf.charger_fichier();
        password = cf.getPassword();

        try {
            Enumeration en = ks.aliases();
            String ALIAS = "";
            Vector vectaliases = new Vector();
            while (en.hasMoreElements())
                vectaliases.add(en.nextElement());
            String[] aliases = (String []) (vectaliases.toArray(new String[0]));
            for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++)
                if (ks.isKeyEntry(aliases[i]))
                {
                    ALIAS = aliases[i];
                    break;
                }

            privatekey = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(ALIAS, password);
            return privatekey;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        }



    public PublicKey getPublickey(){

        chargement_fichier cf = new chargement_fichier(); 
        ks = cf.charger_fichier();
        password = cf.getPassword();

        try {
            Enumeration en = ks.aliases();
            String ALIAS = "";
            Vector vectaliases = new Vector();
            while (en.hasMoreElements())
                vectaliases.add(en.nextElement());
            String[] aliases = (String []) (vectaliases.toArray(new String[0]));
            for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++)
                if (ks.isKeyEntry(aliases[i]))
                {
                    ALIAS = aliases[i];
                    break;
                }

            publickey = ks.getCertificate(ALIAS).getPublicKey();
            return publickey;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null ;
        }
         }

    public X509Certificate getCert(){

        chargement_fichier cf = new chargement_fichier(); 
        ks = cf.charger_fichier();
        password = cf.getPassword();

        try {
            Enumeration en = ks.aliases();
            String ALIAS = "";
            Vector vectaliases = new Vector();
            while (en.hasMoreElements())
                vectaliases.add(en.nextElement());
            String[] aliases = (String []) (vectaliases.toArray(new String[0]));
            for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++)
                if (ks.isKeyEntry(aliases[i]))
                {
                    ALIAS = aliases[i];
                    break;
                }
            cert = (X509Certificate)ks.getCertificate(ALIAS);
            return cert;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        }

}
```

**

and here is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/cryptopro/CryptoProObjectIdentifiers
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.GOST3411$Mappings.configure(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.loadAlgorithms(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at tn.ance.signature.chargement_fichier.charger_fichier(chargement_fichier.java:16)
    at tn.ance.signature.main_project.main(main_project.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.cryptopro.CryptoProObjectIdentifiers
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.

loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 9 more
```

**

**update**
I added the  bcprov-jdk16-1.45 to the folder C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib and added it to the path of external jars in the project but now i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: gostR3411
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.GOST3411$Mappings.configure(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.loadAlgorithms(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
at tn.ance.signature.chargement_fichier.charger_fichier(chargement_fichier.java:15)
at tn.ance.signature.main_project.main(main_project.java:13)
```

Comment: What other bouncycastle libraries do you use? It seems like you mixed up different versions, since I can't find the package "org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider" in the version for jdk 1.6 but it's in older versions: [click](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47)

Comment: I didn't mix them (as far as I know :s) I deleted the old one and just added this one

Comment: Do you have any other BC libraries included or in the lib folder of your JDK? Btw you usually shouldn't add libs to your JDK (because there are only general libs). Usually you just add it to the classpath of your project. So you may want to clean your JDKs libs folder and just add your libs as external jars in your classpath

Comment: No I don't have others other than the ones already existing. I will make sure to clean that folder then, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

Try using jdk15on-152 - the 1.45 release is end-of-lifed. The jar versions with jdk15on in their name are for JDK 1.5 to JDK 1.8 (we tried jdk15+ originally, but it turned out maven could not cope with the +).